# NVIDIA-SMI not working in Windows Docker Container

Tags: docker, nvidia-docker

I'm trying to create a Windows Docker Container with access to GPUs. To start I just wanted to try check if I can access GPU on Docker containers.

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows:1903
CMD [ "ping", "-t", "localhost" ]
```

#### Build and run

```
docker build -t debug_image .
docker run -d --gpus all --mount src="C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVSMI",target="C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVSMI",type=bind debug_image
docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID powershell
```

#### Problem and question

Now that I'm inside, I try to **execute my shared NVIDIA SMI executable**. However, I got an error and it's not capable of running. The obvious question is why, if the host is capable.

```
PS C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVSMI> .\nvidia-smi.exe
```

> NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA
>   driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and
>   running. This can also be  happening if non-NVIDIA GPU is running as
>   primary display, and NVIDIA GPU is in  WDDM mode.

1. About NVIDIA Driver, AFAIK it should not return any problem, since it works on the HOST, where NVIDIA Driver is installed.
2. My host has 2 NVIDIA GPUs, and it has no "primary" display as it's a server with no screen connected. AFAIK, it's CPU doesn't have an integrated GPU, so I would assume one of the connected NVIDIA GPUs is the primary display (if it does exist when no display is connected to the server)(also, I think one should be it, because one renders the screen when I connect through TeamViewer if needed, and `dxdiag` returns one of them as `Display 1`).
3. About WDDM mode, I've found [ways to change it](http://mnnguyen.com/nvidia/), but didn't found ways to check the current mode.

So basically the question, **is why is it not working?** Any insight or help in the previous points would be helpful.

**Update**.

About:

1) I've updated my drivers from 431 to 441, latest version available for `GTX 1080 Ti`, and the error message remains the same.

2-3) I've [confirmed](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/961020/is-gtx1080-compatible-with-tcc-mode-/) that GTX (Except some Titan models) cannot run in TCC mode. Therefore they're running in WDDM mode.